# event.currentTarget.activeElement not working in Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have form with multiple submit buttons and on form submission i am checking which button has been clicked via

```
$('.edit_form').submit(function() {
 var btn = event.currentTarget.activeElement
```

Its not working in Chrome browser. How to resolve this, I don't want to use

```
$('.btn').live("click",function(){
  $('.edit_form').submit();
})
```

Comment: use .on()... .live() is deprecated. .on() has better delagation of events

Comment: I am not using live i am using submit

Comment: I was commenting about the I don't want to use part..

Answer (score 1):

Only IE sets the event as a global property (well not exactly, see comment). What you need is to use the event passed as first argument to your callback.

Use

```
$('.edit_form').submit(function(event) { // <== pass the event
   var btn = event.currentTarget.activeElement
```

But binding on the form when you want the button seems strange. You probably shouldn't do that. Consider that the form may receive the `submit` event directly, without any button involved.

Comment: *"Only IE sets the event as a global property."* Actually, that's not true. Chrome does too, to throw a bone to bonehead sites that only test on IE. But more to the point, the global `event` won't be the jQuery event, it'll be the raw one. So your answer is right, just that statement isn't (quite). :-)

Comment: why shouldn't he do that?  Seems like a perfectly valid thing to do in this case - he's trapping the "submit" event, not a button click.

Comment: I have this above the code mentioned `$(document).bind('pageinit',function(event) {`